# White notification icon won't turn into black on white status bar

Tags: android, colors, notifications, material-design, statusbar

I am using white notification icon. When status bar is white, all apps notification icons turn into black but my apps icon stays white, so becomes invisible. How can I make status bar icon color adaptive? It must be black or white according to light or dark status bar.

It should just turn into light(white) or dark(black) but it won't.

Comment: just change your theme from dark to light

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by decreasing the resolution of the image from 1024 to 32.